# Is there some method to clean all model in Django (clean table in database)?

Tags: django, methods, django-models

Is there some method to clean all model in Django (clean table in database)?
I cant understand by reading official documentation because I'm not a native speaker, but I'm doing my best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `reset` subcommand of `django-admin` or `manage.py`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#reset-appname-appname) will drop and recreate the tables for the supplied apps. For example, `python manage.py reset auth` will drop and recreate the tables for the django.contrib.auth application.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your main app's directory and use manage.py:

```
python ./manage.py --help
python ./manage.py sqlclear --help
```

Use that for apps.